# Users for Hadoop deployment

Tags: hadoop

I followed instructions found online to install and configuring a "2 name nodes" + "10 data nodes" hadoop cluster on CentOS 8.

I created a wheel user called "hadoop" on all nodes and setup passwordless ssh under this user.

The install and configuration were done under root.

When I start up all services, ssh to all nodes are showing "access denied"

What user should I use for hadoop installation?

What user should I use for hadoop operations?

Answer (score 1):

Install services using the 'hadoop' user as you have already configure password-less ssh for this and also for post installation activities (you can use 'sudo' only if required).